# How to make a generic Vertex so that I can create Graphs (Collections) with mixed types?

Tags: ios, swift, graph

I am having trouble with a design of a Vertex struct. I want to be able to create "Array" or "Set" so my "Vertex" doesnt all have to be the same type. Both situations are giving different errors. Check code below.

Thank you in advance

```
import Foundation

public struct Vertex<T: Equatable> where  T: Equatable, T: Hashable {

    public var data: T
    public let index: Int?

    init(data: T , index: Int ) {
        self.data = data
        self.index = index
      }

}

extension Vertex: CustomStringConvertible {

    public var description: String {
        return "\(index): \(data)"
    }

}

struct Coordinate {
    var x : Int
    var y : Int

    init(x : Int, y: Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }

}
extension Coordinate: Equatable {}

func ==(lhs: Coordinate, rhs: Coordinate) -> Bool {
    guard lhs.x == rhs.x else {
        return false
    }

    guard lhs.y == rhs.y else {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

extension Coordinate: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return "\(x)\(y)".hashValue
    }
}




let coord1  = Coordinate(x : 5, y: 5)
let stringVertex1  = Vertex(data: "Hello World", index: 3)
let stringVertex2  = Vertex(data: "Foo ", index: 3)
let intVertex1  = Vertex(data: 2, index: 1)
let coordVertex1  = Vertex(data: coord1, index: 1)


//Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Vertex<String>' to expected element type 'Vertex'. 
//Even if I make myArr1 equal to [stringVertex1, stringVertex1], I still get the same error.
let myArr1 : Array<Vertex> = [stringVertex1, intVertex1]

//This works since the data inside "Vertex" is the same type.
let myArr2 : Array<Vertex<String>> = [stringVertex1, stringVertex2]

//Error: Type "Vertex" does not conform to protocol "Hashable". 
let mySet1 : Set<Vertex> = [stringVertex1, stringVertex2]
```

Comment: Instead of trying to roll your own graph framework, you may want to use one that's already tested and has support for generic vertices: https://github.com/davecom/SwiftGraph
I'm the author though, so I'm a little biased.

Comment: For the first error, you need to implement the `Hashable` protocol for `Coordinate`. For the second error, you'll need a type eraser, `AnyEraser` that erases away the particular type of vertex and lets it be treated as any other https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-type-erasure/

Comment: @Muhammad Absolutely non of that made any sense.

Comment: @Muhammad But String, double and int are all hashable already... where's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer. This is the final vertex code. THE POWER OF POP!

```
public enum TypeOfVertex : String {
    case Int = "Mirror for Int"
    case Float = "Mirror for Float"
    case Double = "Mirror for Double"
    case Coordinates = "Mirror for Coordinate"
    case String = "Mirror for String"

}


protocol AnyVertexable {
    var type: TypeOfVertex { get set }
    var index: Int { get set }

}


struct Vertex<Element : Hashable> : AnyVertexable where Element: Equatable & Hashable {

    var type : TypeOfVertex
    var index: Int
    var data : Element?

    init(index: Int, data: Element) {
        self.data = data
        self.index = index
        if let type = TypeOfVertex(rawValue: data.hashValue.customMirror.description) {
           self.type = type
        } else {
           fatalError()
        }
    }

}

let sample1 = Vertex(index: 0, data: 1.0)
let sample2 = Vertex(index: 2, data: 1)
let sample3 = Vertex(index: 3, data: Coordinate(x: 5, y: 5))

let myArr : [AnyVertexable] = [sample1, sample2, sample3]
```